# Far Cry 5 & far Cry New Dawn run minimized after Launching

Tags: pc, far-cry-5, far-cry-new-dawn

I installed both far cry 5 and new dawn and both installed successfully.
but when I run it starts minimized and I can hear the game sound but can't maximize the screen.
even if I maximize it with task manager there is only a black screen.
I can hear that controls work fine and game is running but I screen is black

I have the latest drivers for my rx570 and sound card.
I reinstalled many times but in vain.
please help.

Comment: Two things to try so you can rule them out: Verify the game files via Steam; run the program as an administrator.